# How do I get a string array from an async task into an image adapter?

Tags: android, bitmap, fragment

I am trying to adapt the google example BitmapFun of processing bitmaps into my own code. I get the picture urls from a mysql database via JSON through an async task (SearchDaMovies). The problem is, I can't get the pictures to load in the image adapter. It works with the example array "imageThumbUrls". But when I replace the "imageThumbUrls" string array with the string array I need, "arrayS", it gives me a NullPointerException. How should I do this? I've been stuck on this for a week.

```
public class ImageGridFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "ImageGridFragment";
private static final String IMAGE_CACHE_DIR = "thumbs";

private int mImageThumbSize;
private int mImageThumbSpacing;
private ImageAdapter mAdapter;
private ImageFetcher mImageFetcher;

String id, name, year, genre, known, tag1, tag2, tag3, poster, oster, description, vote ;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
jParser parser = new jParser();
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> movies;
private static final String urlGetPid = "http://linkpictures.com";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
JSONArray jArray = null;
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_POSTER = "poster";
int success;


/**
 * Empty constructor as per the Fragment documentation .
 */
public ImageGridFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    mImageThumbSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_thumbnail_size);
    mImageThumbSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.image_thumbnail_spacing);

    mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity());

    ImageCacheParams cacheParams = new ImageCacheParams(getActivity(), IMAGE_CACHE_DIR);

    cacheParams.setMemCacheSizePercent(0.25f); // Set memory cache to 25% of app memory

    // The ImageFetcher takes care of loading images into our ImageView children asynchronously
    mImageFetcher = new ImageFetcher(getActivity(), mImageThumbSize);
    mImageFetcher.setLoadingImage(R.drawable.empty_photo);
    mImageFetcher.addImageCache(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), cacheParams);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    movies = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    new SearchDaMovies().execute();

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_show_movies, container, false);
    final ListView mGridView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    name = extras.getString("name");
    year = extras.getString("year");
    known = extras.getString("known");
    genre = extras.getString("genre");
    tag1 = extras.getString("tag1");
    tag2 = extras.getString("tag2");
    tag3 = extras.getString("tag3");
    vote = extras.getString("vote");
    description = extras.getString("description");



    mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mGridView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int scrollState) {
            // Pause fetcher to ensure smoother scrolling when flinging
            if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                mImageFetcher.setPauseWork(true);
            } else {
                mImageFetcher.setPauseWork(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mImageFetcher.setExitTasksEarly(false);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mImageFetcher.setPauseWork(false);
    mImageFetcher.setExitTasksEarly(true);
    mImageFetcher.flushCache();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mImageFetcher.closeCache();
}

@TargetApi(16)
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    if (Utils.hasJellyBean()) {

        ActivityOptions options =
                ActivityOptions.makeScaleUpAnimation(v, 0, 0, v.getWidth(), `v.getHeight());`

    } else {

    }
}

public class SearchDaMovies extends AsyncTask<String, String, String[]>{

String[] arrayS;

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... args) {



        try {

        // send the query to JSON 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();            
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", year));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("genre", genre));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("known", known));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag1", tag1));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag2", tag2));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag3", tag3));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("vote", vote));

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("poster", poster));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));


        //receive the JSON data
        JSONObject json = parser.makeHttpRequest(urlGetPid, params);

        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1){
             jArray = json.getJSONArray("Table");

            for (int i =0; i<jArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
                String id = c.getString("pid");
                String ame = c.getString("name");
                String ear = c.getString("year");
                String enre = c.getString("genre");
                String nown = c.getString("known");
                String ag1 = c.getString("tag1");

                String ote = c.getString("vote");


                if (ote.length()>14){

                ote = ote.substring(0, ote.length() - 14);
                }

                 oster = c.getString("poster");

                 //get the posters in an array
                 arrayS= new String[100];
                 arrayS[i]=oster;
                 Log.d("weird array  ", arrayS[i]);
                String escription = c.getString("description");


                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("pid", id);
                map.put("name", ame);
                map.put("year", ear);
                map.put("genre", enre);
                map.put("known",nown);
                map.put("tag1", ag1);

                map.put("vote", ote);
                map.put("poster", oster);
                map.put("description", escription);
                movies.add(map);




            }


        }
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arrayS;

    }


}


/**
 * The main adapter that backs the GridView. This is fairly standard except the number of
 * columns in the GridView is used to create a fake top row of empty views as we use a
 * transparent ActionBar and don't want the real top row of images to start off covered by it.
 */
public final static String[] imageThumbUrls = new String[] {
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-55osAWw3x0Q/URquUtcFr5I/AAAAAAAAAbs/rWlj1RUKrYI/s160-c/A%252520Photographer.jpg",
    "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/--dq8niRp7W4/URquVgmXvgI/AAAAAAAAAbs/-gnuLQfNnBA/s160-c/A%252520Song%252520of%252520Ice%252520and%252520Fire.jpg",
    "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-7qZeDtRKFKc/URquWZT1gOI/AAAAAAAAAbs/hqWgteyNXsg/s160-c/Another%252520Rockaway%252520Sunset.jpg",
    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/--L0Km39l5J8/URquXHGcdNI/AAAAAAAAAbs/3ZrSJNrSomQ/s160-c/Antelope%252520Butte.jpg",
    "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8HO-4vIFnlw/URquZnsFgtI/AAAAAAAAAbs/WT8jViTF7vw/s160-c/Antelope%252520Hallway.jpg",
    "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-WIuWgVcU3Qw/URqubRVcj4I/AAAAAAAAAbs/YvbwgGjwdIQ/s160-c/Antelope%252520Walls.jpg",
};
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private int mItemHeight = 0;
    private int mNumColumns = 0;
    private int mActionBarHeight = 0;
    private GridView.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;
   // private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> movies = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    public ImageAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
        mImageViewLayoutParams = new GridView.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        // Calculate ActionBar height
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(
                android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
            mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
                    tv.data, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Size + number of columns for top empty row
        return imageThumbUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position < mNumColumns ?
                null : imageThumbUrls[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position < mNumColumns ? 0 : position - mNumColumns;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // Two types of views, the normal ImageView and the top row of empty views
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return (position < mNumColumns) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
        // First check if this is the top row
        if (position < mNumColumns) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = new View(mContext);
            }
            // Set empty view with height of ActionBar
            convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mActionBarHeight));
            return convertView;
        }

        // Now handle the main ImageView thumbnails
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, instantiate and initialize
            imageView = new RecyclingImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
        } else { // Otherwise re-use the converted view
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        // Check the height matches our calculated column width
        if (imageView.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
            imageView.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
        }

        // Finally load the image asynchronously into the ImageView, this also takes care of
        // setting a placeholder image while the background thread runs
        mImageFetcher.loadImage(imageThumbUrls[position],
                 imageView);
        return imageView;
    }


    // * Sets the item height. Useful for when we know the column width so the height can be set
    // * to match.
   //
    // * @param height

    public void setItemHeight(int height) {
        if (height == mItemHeight) {
            return;
        }
        mItemHeight = height;
        mImageViewLayoutParams =
                new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
        mImageFetcher.setImageSize(height);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        mNumColumns = numColumns;
    }

    public int getNumColumns() {
        return mNumColumns;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is way too much code. Post the logcat and try to cut down the code to where you are getting the error. We will kindly ask for more if we need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override`onPostExecute` of your async task `SearchDaMovies` to actually use `arrayS`. It is called after `doInBackground` has finished.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
    // result is your arrayS
    // Perform actions with it
}
```